# Store view switch does not work right when i am in products category and changing the store language

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, menu, language

Now let's explain the problem better.

I have a `magento` e-shop with 2 store views, i have created two main menus for each store view.

Everything works fine when i am at the home page and change the store view to the english one.
And also the other way around, from English to greek.

But when i am in a category from the menu and try to change the language i get no results because the path that i see is not right.

And what i mean by that, let's say for example that i am in the t-shirts category in the greek store view the path that is displayed below the menu says:

```
Home(in greek)->Products(in greek)->t-shirts(in greek)
```

and when i change the language i see the following menu which is wrong:

```
Home(in english)->Products(in greek)->t-shirts(in greek)
```

and of course it does not return any results. What i have done wrong here and how i can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the following:
Only one menu is needed, so you create your menu under `Catalog -> Manage Categories` at the language that you are going to set as default,also remember to give at every menu item url key, then you change store view and rename those menu items to whatever language you want to use, you have to rename the url keys too. Every menu item item should also have a url in the `all store view scope`. And after that you are done. Everything works just fine.